# DNS resolution not working as expected with Pi Hole

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and the machine is connected to my LAN via wifi.

I setup a raspberry pi hole on my local network and I want it to be my primary DNS.

The command `resolvectl status` looks OK to me for the wifi interface:

```
Link 3 (wlp111s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS              
DefaultRoute setting: yes              
       LLMNR setting: yes              
MulticastDNS setting: no               
  DNSOverTLS setting: no               
      DNSSEC setting: no               
    DNSSEC supported: no               
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.11     
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.11     
                      2001:578:3f::30  
                      2001:578:3f:1::30
          DNS Domain: ~.               
                      lan
```

I can even even do an `nslookup` on the raspberry pi:

```
$ nslookup 192.168.0.11
11.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa   name = pi.hole.
```

However, when I try to ping `pi.hole`, it looks like it is going out to my ISP's DNS (I have no idea how it figured out my ISP's DNS servers!)

```
$ ping pi.hole
PING pi.hole(pi.hole (2600:8800:1300:344:2372:fc5f:b162:37d3)) 56 data bytes
```

I expected `pi.hole` to resolve to `192.168.0.11`

Comment: This forum is for Ubuntu related questions. please post your question on this forum:https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I originally thought my problem was how I configured resolvctl on Ubuntu. Now I'm not so sure. It might be a quirk of the pi hole software.

Comment: Maybe try a name without a dot: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523028/valid-characters-of-a-hostname  The nslookup output wasn't pi.hole.lan like I expected. Can you ping pi.hole.lan? Pre 20.04, there was a need for the libnss-resolve package, but that doesn't seem to be needed in 20.04.

Comment: I am an idiot. I was connected to a VPN when I tried to ping another host on my LAN. Sorry everyone.

Comment: Based on the above comment by OP I am voting to close this question as not reproducible.

Comment: @user68186, I don't know, I think it's useful to have these goofy errors recorded too - "pi.hole on local network doesn't respond to ping because ping was sent to VPN" seems highly reproducible!

Comment: @pbhj The exact language is: 

**This describes a problem that can't be reproduced, that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your [router DNS settings](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-dns-servers-on-most-popular-routers-2617995) and make your pi-hole your router's primary DNS. Then all internet traffic will be routed through the pi-hole.

Or [manually change](https://www.howtogeek.com/167533/the-ultimate-guide-to-changing-your-dns-server/) the DNS's all the computers on your network.

If your configuration is correct, then you should be able to access http://pi.hole or your pi's ip address from any computer on you LAN.

Comment: The DHCP on the router is disabled. The DHCP on the pi.hole is enabled. It turns out I can ping other hosts on the LAN, like "london" and "milan". For whatever reason, I cannot ping the hostname of the DHCP server itself ("pi.hole"). I think resolvectl is configured correctly. Might be just a limitation of Pi Hole.

Comment: @ahoffer Maybe this might solve your problem: https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/pi-hole-resolves-but-i-cant-ping-it-wat/22339